# RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found

Tags: solr, ruby-on-rails-4

I got the following error when i tried to run "rake sunspot:solr:reindex". Does anyone has idea how to fix this? It used to be running fine until recently.

```
RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found
Error:     Not Found

Request Data: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><delete><query>type:Place</query></delete>"

Backtrace: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:268:in `adapt_response'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:175:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:161:in `send_and_receive'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-d013ad3c9f86/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in `block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/sunspot-d013ad3c9f86/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:15:in `send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
(eval):2:in `post'
```

Full error code at https://gist.github.com/DerekChia/36ebe381451b2c4cf18d

Comment: have u started solr server before reindexing?

Comment: As Gopal pointed out, there is probably a connection issue. Either the server is not running or you are using wrong parameters for connection

Comment: Somehow i got it running after rebooting the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am new to solr and had the same issue getting it working in development.  When I ran everything as sudo, it started up with no problems:

```
$ sudo bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
$ sudo bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex
```

I could then view the solr server at `http://localhost:8982/solr`

So it looks like a permissions issue to avoid having to run it as root.